# Как понять в чем ошибка?

Tags: php, curl

При подключению к сайту выдает - HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error Server: nginx Date: Thu, 20 Apr 2022 06:00:10 GMT Content-Type: text/html Content-Length: 186 Connection: close

Как понять из-за чего сайт дропает ?

Пытался изменять заголовки, менял прокси - результат один выдает.

На сайте идет загрузка(заглушка) и потом перенаправляет на главную сайта, я так понимаю идут проверки на заглушке и выбор сервера.

Пытался подставить куки - тоже не дало результата.
На сайте есть js, но вроде при прогрузке страниц только тянет js файлы.

Так же сайт отвечает заголовками если через браузер смотреть:

```
x-content-type-options
    nosniff
X-Content-Type-Options
    nosniff
x-frame-options
    DENY
X-Frame-Options
    DENY
X-Xss-Protection
    1; mode=block
```

а остальные стандартные вроде заголовки в ответе

Comment: если есть доступ к сайту то идти смотреть логи. если нет, и вы пытаетесь сделать некий парсер, то аккуратно эмулировать запрос, скорее всего дело в передаваемых параметрах или теле запроса

Comment: Да, парсинг сайта. В этом и сложность, попробовал заголовки взять которые браузер отправляет и смена айпи - тот-же результат. 
На сайте идет загрузка изначально заглушка обычная(я так понимаю выбор сервера), а потом уже грузится сайт, но вроде никуда не перенаправляет, а просто редерикт так-же на главную на этой же странице.
Пробовал брать уже с куками тоже самое.

Comment: Как вам уже сказали - это серверная ошибка. Если сайт не ваш - то никак, нет доступа к его логам - тем более.

Comment: давайте уже ссыль на сайт, и что оттуда хотите утянуть. а также код, которым пытаетесь это сделать.

Comment: К сожалению не могу дать ссылку. Меня интересует где копаться просто ?

Answer (score 0):

500 - всегда ошибка на сервере и в частности в php скрипте. Соответственно надо смотреть что не так в скрипте, например отладкой или в логах

Comment: Парсер сайта, к логам нету доступа. 
То есть сайту что-то не нравится, но как это понять что именно?

Comment: @rollingbl если у вас нет доступа к серверу, то никак, только пытаться угадать

Comment: это понять, но можно как-нибудь облегчить ситуацию? А то вообще не понятно из-за чего выдает такую ошибку.